# I am trying TDD(Test Driven Development) using Laravel8 inbuilt PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, tdd

I am receiving this error:

> Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::visit()

while running my test cases. I am a bit new to TDD.

Here is my ExampleTest Code

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public function test_example()
    {
        $response = $this->visit('/')->see('Laravel');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```

From the video tutorial that I am using to learn about TDD the code above runs well without any issue but when it comes to running the code on my side I am faced with error as shown below :

> • Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > example
> Error
>
> Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::visit()

I am currently running `Laravel 8.6` and `PHPUnit 9.510`

Any ideas on how I can resolve this are highly welcomed.

Comment: Could there be some breaking changes between PHPUnit 4.8 and 9.5.10 as the code above work well in PHPUnit 4.8

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are mixing up Laravel's built in browser testing methods ([Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#navigation)) - like `visit()` that you are using above - with the [unit testing and feature testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing) methods.

As you are in the `Tests\Feature` namespace you need to follow the guide for unit and feature testing, the equivalent of which are:

```
public function test_example()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: It looks more like OP is trying to use methods from https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing which are the old Laravel (prior to 5.3) browser testing methods

Comment: Thank you. It worked. That was the issue